# can't insert values in sql via ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

i'm trying to understand this error but i dont how to solve it
this is my JS code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VisionwareHelp\\Php/CriaUserEempresa.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: ({Pname: Pname, Uname: Uname, email: email, Ename: Ename, Sigla: Sigla}),
                complete:function(data) 
                {
                    resposta = data;
                    console.log(resposta);
                }
            });
```

this is my php code:

```
$serverName = $server;
$uid = $uid;
$pwd = $pass;
$connectionInfo = array( "UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd,"Database"=>"Portal");
//$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Portal");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$Pname = $_POST["Pname"];
$Uname = $_POST["Uname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$Ename = $_POST["Ename"];
$Sigla = $_POST["Sigla"];

if( $conn )
{
    $sqlCliente = "INSERT INTO Portal.dbo.Empresa VALUES ($Ename, $Sigla)";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCliente)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sqlCliente . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}
```

when i do console.log of data, give me this:
[image: log]

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: ,did u get any error?

Comment: what about the HTML form that goes with this?

Comment: you also have syntax errors in your query. `mysqli_error($conn);` should be throwing you something; what is it? I know what it is, we need "you" to tell us. Oh, and you're open to some major SQL injection here.

Comment: i cant see mysqli_error($conn), i only can see that statusText. if i replace, resposta = data; for resposta = data.responseText; give me  undefined

Comment: plus, you have another major problem regarding SQL/connection. Ask the people who have provided you with answers. I for one, will not be submitting an answer or ***am very hesitant*** to do so, since there are too many things that are first unknown, and problematic with your code. Nobody below picked up on those. *"what is wrong with my code?"* - ***A: Too many things.***

Comment: Thanks for the heads of SQL injection, for the rest, I'm wrong, I know, but thanks anyway for the answers, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Try to change into `$sqlCliente = "INSERT INTO Portal.dbo.Empresa VALUES ('$Ename', '$Sigla')";`

Comment: care to enlighten everyone and fill in the "try..." with something more substantial? ;-)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to explain what your suggestion does and why it might help, especially if you're uncertain whether or not it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your sql insert statement.

```
$sqlCliente = "INSERT INTO Portal.dbo.Empresa(Ename,Sigla) VALUES ($Ename, $Sigla)";
```

OR

```
$sqlCliente = "INSERT INTO Portal.dbo.Empresa VALUES ($Ename, $Sigla,..... Add all parameters to here)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`url: 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VisionwareHelp\\Php/CriaUserEempresa.php',`

This line is incorrect.

PHP files need a server to get executed. By the looks of your path, it looks like you have hosted in IIS. IIS doesn't suppport PHP by default - so assuming you have installed PHP and configured properly, read below.

You don't post to the physical path of the PHP file, rather URL of the PHP.

Therefore, it should look something similar to:

`url: localhost/VisionwareHelp/php/CriaUserEempresa.php',`

Until you fix the URL to the correct one, none of your posting code will work correctly.

If you have not installed PHP on IIS, then you need to download and install a PHP-enabled server like '[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)' and host your PHP in that.

Also, read below articles - it will help to improve your knowledge.

- [Installing and Testing Wampserver](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html)
- [Beginner’s Guide to Ajax Development with PHP](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)

Comment: You're getting warm, but you missed quite a few things. Look at their code again and study it very carefully. What doesn't "belong"? To be a bit more precise, what doesn't belong "together"? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say @Fred-ii-. If you know the answer, why don't you post the answer? It should help the OP :)

Comment: I'd like to Pasan, but there are too many things wrong with the OP's code, including which API they want or "can" use in order to connect with. Their question is way "too hot" for me to touch. Sorry, but I've submitted answers in the past for ones like this, and only end up in endless comments under the answer I give. Call it "experience" ;-)

Comment: :D sure thing - now I understand! I am new to SO but I've been active in CO for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax, The correct syntax of sending multiple data is: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So, **Replace**

```
data: ({Pname: Pname, Uname: Uname, email: email, Ename: Ename, Sigla: Sigla}),
```

**with**

```
data: {'Pname':Pname, 'Uname':'Uname', 'email':email, 'Ename':Ename, 'Sigla':Sigla },
```

And  this line `url: 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VisionwareHelp\\Php/CriaUserEempresa.php',`  is also incorrect.

**replace**

```
url: 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VisionwareHelp\\Php/CriaUserEempresa.php',
```

**with**

```
url: 'Php/CriaUserEempresa.php',
```

Hope it will help you..